# Jaybird Bluebuds x - Bluetooth does not work

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, headphones

I've had my Bluebuds x for a while now, but they suddenly stopped connecting to any device, seems like Bluetooth is not working. I've already reset it, but it doesn't work. I can hear it saying "power on" and "searching for you music device" but no devices are able to find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit to include result from terminal for `lsusb; hciconfig -a; rfkill list all`

Comment: what is lsusb; hciconfig -a; rfkill?

Comment: commands to run in terminal (CTRL + t) lsusb lists usb devices detected- bluetooth devices tend to be USB even when they are part of a wifi card, hciconfig -a will show stats about bluetooth and rfkill will show if wireless devices are enabled/disabled by hardware switch or software

Answer (score 0):

```
veon@veon-XPS-15-9550:~$ lsusb; hciconfig -a; rfkill list all
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:6410 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 44:1C:A8:E4:49:78  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:13270 acl:0 sco:0 events:935 errors:0
    TX bytes:5769 acl:0 sco:0 commands:640 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'veon-XPS-15-9550'
    Class: 0x0c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x1000
    LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x2105
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)

10: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
11: phy6: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```